# Native and managed size dll size

Tags: .net, dll, c++-cli

A mixed mode C++/cli dll compiles to a file larger than I expected, 6800 KB in debug and 3700 KB in release.  I suspect that the managed part is unnecessary large, because although only one .cpp is compiled with /clr, lots of stuff is getting pull through headers.  Reflector shows a ton of .net definitions for native structs, and when I try to use set next instruction in the debugger, two options are presented.

I bet that if I include fewer headers from my managed cpp, things will improve, but I'd like to measure before acting.  What tool can display how much native and managed bytes a dll has?

Comment: What does "too big" mean exactly? In today's world of cheap 1TB drives, can anything constructible really be too big?

Comment: How are you creating the dlls? How big are they? Does the line of code count differ?

Comment: Also are they debug builds?

Comment: I've added the sizes for debug and release builds to the question.

Answer (score 1):

One tool is DUMPBIN.EXE. Open the Visual Studio Command Tools prompt and then `dumpbin /?` to get information about options. The command:

```
dumpbin /headers /clrheader name.dll
```

Will get you started.

Comment: That's the kind of tool I was looking for, but it doesn't seem to separate native and managed parts.